# Converting plain text HTML file to binary Excel 97-2003

Tags: php, excel

I have an 'Excel' file (with a .xls extension) which turns out to be a plain text HTML file masquerading as a spreadsheet (if I run 'file [filename]' I get 'HTML document text' as the type). The file comes from a third party supplier and I have no control over the format.

I want to convert the file into Excel 97-2003 format so that I can read it in a PHP library (PHPExcel). I can do this by opening the file in Excel, ignoring the warning message and then explicitly saving it as Excel 97-2003, but I want to automate the whole process from the initial file coming in to extracting the cell data and dumping it into a database.

Ideally I'd like to use a PHP library for the conversion, because that would integrate better with the rest of the codebase, but libraries written in Perl, Java or (at a pinch) C# would also work, provided they don't rely on the server running Windows and Office.

Is there a tool or library available which can provide this functionality?

Comment: I'm part completed the PHPExcel Reader for HTML now, though as a fairly basic "experimental" reader.... it all depends how sophisticated the html spreadsheet you're trying to read actually is (e.g. nested tables, merged cells), and whether you need styling information or simply the raw data

Comment: I've noticed that, but I don't think it's in the production release or documented yet?

Comment: It isn't yet in a production release.... at the moment, I'm still working on the nested tables and merged cells logic; and once that's completed there's still styles to look at and the rich text component. My anticipated "ready" date is around Easter this year, for a 1.7.8 release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for the moment the only answer is to manually process the file by opening it in Excel and re-saving it, which does work but doesn't allow for complete automation.

I'll take a look at the new version of PHPExcel with HTML support once it has been released though as that sounds promising.

Answer (score 2):

PhpExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ is decent but you'll have issues with it gobbling up memory with large sheets.  For large sheets or speed I'd recommend perl writeExcel http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm

The perl writeExcel library is faster and uses less memory than PhpExcel. I then use

```
<?php
    echo passthru('perl filename.pl');
?>
```

to run the perl script through PHP.

Comment: I have no problems with PHPExcel's performance, it works very well even with large sheets.

Speed is not the issue here, the problem is the initial file is not in a format which PHPExcel can handle. I am also looking to read from spreadsheets, so WriteExcel is not relevant.